# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate Search Optimisation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, r2dbc

I'm developing a Spring Boot application right now. It's part of microservice architecture and implements a search using JPA Specifications. And then maps into DTO before returning to results. The schema is like this:

```
Controller --> Service --> JPA: Find entities
JPA --> Service --> Controller: Return 
Controller --> Mapper: Map into DTO (MapStruct)
```

### The problem

The entity I'm doing a search against does have a lot of dependencies (at least
`15` of `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToMany` and `@OneToOne`) and it takes `500ms` to load just one whole entity. So for loading a list of `50` entities, it takes between `5` and `25` s, which is a problem in the microservice architecture.

### What I've tried:

- I've used JCache to reduce the execution time to 5s, from 25s ✅
- I loaded all in `EAGER` mode: It's taking 500ms incompressible time ❌
- I loaded all in `LAZY` mode:

  - it's taking 5ms for all 50 entities before mapping into `DTO` ✅
  - But mapping them into `DTO` causes loading to hibernate proxies -> All over it's taking 500ms again ❌
- I tried using different threads to map to `DTO` (parallelism) -> JPA is blocking anyway, so it's still taking 500ms ❌
- I tried then using `R2DBC` but it's not working properly inside a blocking app, and not resolving relationships anyway ❌

At this point, the only thing I can think of is:

- Changing the application into a reactive one
- Loading each dependency by `ID` manually and using a caching mechanism

This is the point. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Consider using [projections](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-query-projections/) to fetch only the necessary entity properties.

Comment: `But mapping them into DTO causes loading to hibernate proxies -> All over it's taking 500ms again` - i don't work with MapStruct, so this is just a guess, but most probably some getters are invoked reflectively, which causes to load additional data from db. If it's possible with MapStruct, try to create mappers manually (the entire process source -> target manually) in order to make sure you don't accidentally load data you don't need during mapping process.

Comment: @birca123 The fact that we have `@OneToMany` makes it impossible for us to use `projections`

Comment: @Chaosfire the Mapstruct is mapping from internal Domain objects into DTO, by calling getters, and by that, making additional SQL requests. It also doesn't load something we don't want, but just what is needed to be mapped

Comment: @SelastLambou That fact doesn't stop you from using projections, you can still use them in form of interface projections. Where you can use [@EntityGraph](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs) to specify paths of properties that need to be loaded eagerly. The problem is that JPA will still fetch all properties as I pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74162755/10231374). Take a look at [Blaze persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence) library, which could be useful in your case, since it has support for specifications and better projections.